# pdo insert sanitizing html on server, not locally

Tags: html, mysql, pdo, sanitization

I am inserting data from an html editor into my database. I have html purifier setup but have removed it for the example because the problem exists regardless.

```
GLOBAL $DB;

        $queryHandle = $DB->prepare("UPDATE support SET
                                    help = :help
                                    WHERE id = :id");
        $queryHandle->BindParam(':id', $id);
        $queryHandle->BindParam(':help', PDO::PARAM_STR);           
        $queryHandle->execute();
        $queryHandle->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $queryHandle;
        }
```

Help is the html text. Locally it works fine. When I upload my site to my server, the html comes out with \'s behind every quote. I do not have magic quotes or any other sanitization setup. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on which means your server is misconfigured. Turn it off.